# block--[region].tpl.php not working

Tags: 7, theming

I Copied the file

```
bootstrap\theme\system\block.tpl.php
```

to my subtheme

```
bootstrap_subtheme\templates\block.tpl.php
```

I made another 2 copies and renamed them to

```
bootstrap_subtheme\templates\block--sidebar-first.tpl.php
bootstrap_subtheme\templates\block--sidebar_first.tpl.php
```

In the subtheme.info file it says
regions[sidebar_first]  = 'Primary'

The block.tpl override works but the sidebar-first.tpl.php does not get overridden.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have changed the underscore but it doesn't fix my issue.

Comment: You've cleared the cache as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of your template block--sidebar_first.tpl.php is correct. Clear the cache to override the template.
OR 
Put this function in template.php and clear the cache. You will get the suggested template for your block.

On suggested name replace double underscore with double dash for your tpl file, and clear the cache.

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
    print_r($variables['theme_hook_suggestions']);     
}
```

Comment: Using the returned function names.
block--blockgroup-sidebar.tpl.php does not work. 
block--block__52.tpl.php works. Witch is a little odd to me.

Comment: The block--blockgroup_sidebar.tpl.php doesnt work, even after clearing cache.

Comment: can you put here all the actual name suggested by above function?

Comment: Array ( [0] => block__blockgroup-sidebar [1] => block__block [2] => block__block__52 ) Array ( [0] => block__blockgroup-sidebar [1] => block__system [2] => block__system__main_menu ) Array ( [0] => block__blockgroup-sidebar [1] => block__block [2] => block__block__53 )

Comment: block--blockgroup-sidebar.tpl.php is correct as you used earlier. May be some other module override this template.

Comment: Thanks though. I came right with just editing page.tpl.php .